# Fully connected Recurrent Neural Network: question about full connectivity

Tags: neural-networks

Here is the picture of RNN
[image]

It's said, that hidden layer is fully connected(dash dots). But I don't understand why? For example I don't understand why the one from $a_3$ to $a_1$ exists. I thought information transfers from hidden state $a_{t-1}$ to $a_{t}$ and not other way around. Maybe I am confused by terminology.

Can you explain me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed an unconventional way to present the structure of an RNN, and I think your confusion is coming from conflating the time indices with the unit indices. Here's the "unrolled" network, with time indices in superscript:

[image]

In this diagram, each arrow represents a full set of connections from one layer to the other. For example, an arrow between two blue blocks actually stands in for 9 arrows between all the recurrent units of one layer to all the units of the next.

Comment: thank you for your comment! So it means, for example, that units in layer 1 are fully connected with units in layer 2?

Comment: If by "layer" you're referring to the time slices, then yes, the units at time [1] are fully connected to the units at time [2]. This corresponds to the dashed arrows in the figure in the original question.